# XCUITest - Changing expectation poll frequency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I'm writing some Xcode UI tests.

The UI under test is very active, and autonomous. Elements update themselves automatically.

I'm trying to test, for example, that a given `UITextView` contains some text. The text is being updated automatically based on network activity.

I'm finding that my tests are highly unreliable. It seems that this is because the polling interval when evaluating an `NSPredicate` is highly variable.

Reading the docs, I see it says:

```
/**
 * @method -expectationForPredicate:evaluatedWithObject:handler:
 * Creates an expectation that is fulfilled if the predicate returns true when evaluated with the given
 * object. The expectation periodically evaluates the predicate and also may use notifications or other
 * events to optimistically re-evaluate.
 */
```

The key phrase is "periodically evaluates". It seems that the evaluation is often being done too slowly, and the element is being updated too quickly for the predicate to be evaluated in time.

So the question is: **Is there any way to set this polling interval?**

Comment: I would suggest maybe this is not a good thing to UI test.

Comment: @matt that's a fair suggestion, however without going into the specifics, there are some good reasons why this is something that it makes sense to be able to test. The issue I have at the moment is that it seems to run fine on my local machine but not on a remote app automation platform, I suspect because their machines are probably low-spec Mac Minis, perhaps shared between multiple users, and polling much slower than mine... The question is whether I can force a specific poll interval, or Xcode just decides for itself, nondeterministically...

Comment: I do not say it can't be tested. I question whether a UI test is the appropriate mode of testing. You presumably have some code that gives the text view its content; perhaps _that_ is what needs testing. The presence or absence of an _interface_ is probably irrelevant. I don't insist on this point, but it is something worth thinking about. In general I question the need for / value of UI testing in the first place, and this seems a particularly good case in point.